# Data-Table misaligning the title and body of the table when scroll is apply

Tags: jquery, css, datatable, datatables

I'm trying to apply a DataTable jquery plugin on the tables of my template. But when I apply the scroll, the table misalign the title and the body.

You can help-me?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayconfsbrito/faJkw/27/)

The Jquery code which apply DataTable on my table:

```
$(function(){
$('#tabelainfo').dataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": true,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "sScrollY": "200px",
    "sScrollX": "100%",
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bRetrieve": true,
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
});

$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
});
jQuery('#' + idTabela).wrap('<div class="scrollStyle" />');
```

});

See the fiddle below:

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the difference is exactly the width of a vertical scrollbar. This is because you have both `sScrollY` and `sScrollX` on the same page.

The two sections, `.dataTables_scrollHead` and `.dataTables_scrollBody` have both `100%` width, but `.dataTables_scrollBody` is decreased by the width of a vertical scrollbar because you have `sScrollY` also.

So the solution is to expand `.dataTables_scrollBody` with the extra width that is stolen by the vertical scrollbar. See [**how you can calculate the width of a scollbar**](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-scrollbar-width). Typically it is 15.

This must be added to `.dataTables_scrollBody` in *percent*, not pixels. The nearest percentage to 15 in your 1315px table is 2% (26). So add this to your script after the datatable is initialized :

```
$(".dataTables_scrollBody").css('width', '102%');
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/YL7hZ/**

Comment: The problem was solved in JsFiddle, but persist in my tables. I will reproduce the problem in JsFiddle and then post here. Thank you!

Comment: davidkonrad, I'm accepting your answer because you decided what was asked in this question. Thank you so much. So, later I will reproduce the problem in the fiddle, post a new question here in Stack Overflow and mention you.

Comment: The new problem occours just on my template.

Comment: davidkonrad, look the new fiddle with the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/mayconfsbrito/YL7hZ/10/

Comment: @mayconfsbrito, the problem is without doubt the use of `bootstrap.min.css` and `dataTables.bootstrap.css` (??) **without** using `jquery.dataTables.css`. Are you sure `dataTables.bootstrap.css` is uptodate? If I add `jquery.dataTables.css` it somehow works much better -> http://jsfiddle.net/6K9aL/

Comment: However, something is defently being overwritten by some of the CSS-"extensions", breaking datatables sScroll?-logic. Using a "clean" datatables setup you do not have to increase the width of `dataTable_scrollbody`, see this -> http://jsfiddle.net/5SzXR/

Comment: Thank you @davidkonrad. You are a great programmer! Thank you so much. I just add the datatables.bootstrap.css and the problem was solved. So, only to simplify and clarify the solution, how about posting a new answer to the ultimate solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have facing same problem too. This occurred if you have short column table width combined with scrollX option.

So, My solution is set value scrollX to false or just deleted it.

```
"scrollX"       : false,
```

Maybe this answer can  help someone in future.

Comment: This worked for me. I was fiddling with too many changes but finally this answer helped.